# AvalonDock: Keep floating windows visible when minimizing main application

Tags: avalondock, xceed

Is it possibe to keep the floating windows visible when minimizing the main application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. the reason why it is being minimized is because the default owner of the floating window is the main window. so you have to set the `floatingWindow.Owner = null;` then you will also be able to put the main window in front of the floating window. if you want to switch between floating window and main window you can set `floatingWindow.ShowInTaskbar = true;`.

In my code i put it in a selectionChanged event handler so when i pop out a document it fires the selectionChanged event.

Document creation

```
 private void userItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LayoutDocument ld = new LayoutDocument();
        ld.Title = "All Users";
        ld.ToolTip = "Manage all users";
        //selection changed event
        ld.IsSelectedChanged += Ld_IsSelectedChanged;
        ld.IsActiveChanged += Ld_IsSelectedChanged;
        Users users = new Users(ld);
        ld.Content = users;
        LayoutDocumentPane pane = ((todaysPayments.FindParent<LayoutDocumentPane>() ?? (panal.Children?[0] as LayoutDocumentPane)) ?? new LayoutDocumentPane());
        pane.Children.Add(ld);
        if (panal.ChildrenCount == 0)
        {
            panal.Children.Add(pane);
        }
        ld.IsSelected = true;
    }
```

And the event handler

```
public void Ld_IsSelectedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //get the floating windows from the DockingManager
        manager.FloatingWindows.ToList().ForEach(floatingWindow =>
        {
            floatingWindow.Owner = null;
            floatingWindow.ShowInTaskbar = true;
            var fw = floatingWindow.Model as LayoutDocumentFloatingWindow;
            floatingWindow.Title = fw?.RootDocument?.Title ?? "";
        });
    }
```